# How to graph this function with pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to graph the function `log(cos(x)-1)/2-log(cos(x)+1)/2` (the antiderivative of csc(x)). However, it seems the matplotlib.pyplot is having a problem. The graph window opens, but there is no plot (note that no warnings are produced). My test code:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = linspace(-100, 100, 200000)
func = input("")
func = eval(func)
plt.plot(x, func)
plt.show()
```

I checked if the bug is caused by undefined values of the logarithm, but a function like `log(cos(x)+1)/2` or even just the logarithm function with `x=linspace(-100, 100, 200000)` can be graphed. Can anybody confirm why pyplot does this and how to fix it?

Comment: Why do you think `log` should show values for negative values? Wouldn't it be undefined? Normally, a big red warning is shown when you try this. Also note that `from numpy import *` creates a big mess of your local naming space, as many functions have the same name as in standard Python.

Comment: To plot the antiderivative of `csc(x)` you might use `plt.plot(x, np.log(np.abs(1 / np.sin(x) - 1 / np.tan(x))))` (`csc` and `cot` are only defined indirectly in numpy, `np.abs` takes the absolute value).